# Problems using prototype with lowpro through firefox…

Tags: firefox, prototype, lowpro

Seems there's nothing to do… using the combo prototype/lowpro, no problems at all with safari + chrome (webkit based), but firefox does take it at all. Any clues on how to go through this ?
big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails 2.3.4 was buggy on this one... had to add format.js {render :layout => false to make it work.